Finding the number of solutions to $x=1964\sin x-189$

Find the number of solutions of the enigmatic equation $$x=1964\sin x-189$$

We define
$$f(x)=\frac{x+189}{1964} \qquad\text{and}\qquad
g(x)=\sin x$$
We can see that $f(x)$ is monotonic and $|g(x)|\le1$
We want those real numbers $\epsilon$ for which $f(\epsilon)=g(\epsilon)$

We set $f(a)=1$ and $f(b)=-1$ 
$\implies a=1775$ and $b=-2153$
Also $f(c)=0$ at $c=-189$
I can see that in the interval $[-2153,1775]$, $624$ intervals of length $2\pi$ are laid.
After this I am feeling exhausted and unsure about my next step.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
(Also the answer to this question isn't $1250$ solutions).

Did you see this?

His comment that "1250" is not the solution suggests he saw that old question and believes its answer to be wrong. It's still not a good reason to open a duplicate question and leave the old one with a wrong answer :-( And it would have been nice to get some context - where you got this question, and how you know for sure 1250 is wrong.

@Sahaj yes...but the answer given (1250) is wrong

But why is it wrong?

@NadavHar'El someone posted this on a local telegram channel... I don't know the source but I'll inform you as soon as I get to know about it...also the answer given by the poster was 1251...I'll ask him the detailed soln and post here if u wish

I am really sorry for providing the solution as an image instead of typing it out, but the solution is too much, and I really can't write that out. 

If something is wrong in this solution, please feel free to tell.

I like to use https://simpletex.cn/ai/latex_ocr to convert images to latex

@oliH. It's not opening for me atm
